# Which PHP framework would be easy to use for someone who has worked with Spring framework?

Tags: spring, zend-framework, web-applications, cakephp

For past 7 months I have been designing web applications using open source technologies such as Java, Spring framework and PostgreSQL.

I really enjoy the concept of MVC and have used Spring MVC (not very widely) in most of web applications.

I will have to design a big web application using PHP, but I'm not sure which PHP framework (Zend framework or CakePHP) to use, which one would be suitable for a person like me who has used Spring framework for a while.

My main intension is to have a very organized MVC web application, looking at comparision between CakePHP and Zend Framework, it seems that Zend Framework is stronger, but less tutorials and samples in the web in compare to cakePHP.

What do you recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The person who had used any of the MVC framework does not face much problems to ride with any other framework and does not take much time to get familiar with them.

Frameworks are different in their conventions.

You can use any of them all are good and [here](http://www.phpframeworks.com/) is a comparison of various PHP frameworks